# Using fb-contrib library with Gradle's FindBugs plugin

Tags: gradle, findbugs

Is it possible to integrate the [fb-contrib](http://fb-contrib.sourceforge.net/) library with Gradle's [FindBugs plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/findbugs_plugin.html)? I've been looking around for a solution for a while but so far I haven't found anything...

If it helps, here's the script I have right now. It's a work in progress but the report is generated correctly.

```
apply plugin: "findbugs"

task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {

    classes = fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/*.class");
    source = fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/*.java");
    classpath = files()

    findbugs {
            toolVersion = "2.0.3"
            ignoreFailures = true
            effort = "max"
            reportLevel = "low"
            reportsDir = file("${projectDir}/reports/findbugs")
            sourceSets = [it.sourceSets.main, it.sourceSets.test]
    }

    tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
            reports {
                    xml.enabled = false
                    html.enabled = true
            }
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just came across this very same problem. I was able to solve it as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

dependencies {
    // We need to manually set this first, or the plugin is not loaded
    findbugs 'com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:3.0.0'
    findbugs configurations.findbugsPlugins.dependencies

    // To keep everything tidy, we set these apart
    findbugsPlugins 'com.mebigfatguy.fb-contrib:fb-contrib:6.0.0'
}

task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
   // Add all your config here ...

   pluginClasspath = project.configurations.findbugsPlugins
}
```

Hope that helps!

You can add more Findbugs plugins just by adding them under dependencies for `findbugsPlugins`

Comment: If I do it like that. E.g. `task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    toolVersion = "3.0.1"
  ...
  pluginClasspath = project.configurations.findbugsPlugins
}`
I get No such property: toolVersion for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs_Decorated

Comment: @Kutzi `toolVersion` is not a task property. You need to define that property globally using `findbugs { toolVersion = "3.0.1" }`. Check the original question for an example on this.

Answer (score 3):

if you place the fb-contrib.jar in Findbugs' plugin directory, it should just automagically get picked up, i would think. Never tried with Gradle tho.

Comment: `findbugs.jar` is obtained automatically through the maven central repository: `repositories { mavenCentral() }`. Manually adding `fb-contrib.jar` to the folder where 'findbugs.jar' is does not seem to change anything in the output. Oddly, if I add a Maven dependency to the script above... `dependencies { findbugs 'com.mebigfatguy:fbcontrib:3.4.2-hudson-1' }` ...the build process just seems to get stuck while executing the 'findbugs' process. Do you think there is some sort of incompatibility between older versions of `fb-contrib.jar` and v2.0.3 of 'findbugs.jar'?

Comment: why use such an old version? try 5.0.3