# Integrating findsecbugs plugin with Gradle's findbugs plugin

Tags: gradle, findbugs

I am planning to use [findsecbugs](http://h3xstream.github.io/find-sec-bugs/) plugin to scan java code for vulnerabilities using [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) plugin. I am looking for configuration parameters to include in my build.gradle file. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737193/using-fb-contrib-library-with-gradles-findbugs-plugin).

P.S.: I am able to use FindBugs plugin with Gradle.

Comment: An issue about that is open on the repo right now: https://github.com/h3xstream/find-sec-bugs/issues/134

Comment: I went to that issue you mentioned on github and left this fix. Now I am not able to access that page. Getting 404 error.

Comment: Looks like the project was moved: https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/issues/134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and found the working configuration. Posting the working configuration below:

```
  apply plugin: 'java'  
  apply plugin: 'findbugs'    
  apply plugin: 'maven'  
  apply plugin: 'signing'  

  sourceCompatibility = 1.7

  dependencies {  

  findbugs 'com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:3.0.0'
  findbugs configurations.findbugsPlugins.dependencies

  // Here we specify the findbugsPlugins
  findbugsPlugins 'com.h3xstream.findsecbugs:findsecbugs-plugin:1.2.0'
  }  
 task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {

  classes = fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/*.class");
  source = fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/*.java");
  classpath = files()
  pluginClasspath = project.configurations.findbugsPlugins

  findbugs {
   toolVersion = "3.0.0"
   sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
   ignoreFailures = true
   reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
   effort = "max"
   reportLevel = "high"
   includeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/include.xml")
   excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/exclude.xml")
  }

  tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
        reports {
                xml.enabled = false
                html.enabled = true
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you managed to run findbugs and findsecuritybugs together?

Comment: @user902383 Yes, see the dependency section in the above answer.

Comment: Thx, I realised i was excluding regular bugs in my exclude file, but thanks anyway.